# How to use const before declaration in styled-components

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, styled-components

Let me clarify the question. I have a styled component, `const PlanBody`, which needs to receive styling whenever one of his parents, `const PlanContainer`,  is hovered. The problem is that I can't call `${PlanBody}` when declaring `const PlanContainer` because it doesn't exist yet (is declared later in the same file, a few hundred lines below).

Here's my code:

```
const PlanContainer = styled.div<Props>`
/* Property that will change onHover */
  flex: 1 1 0px;

    &:hover {
      ${PlanBody} {
        /* Property being overridden */
        flex: 1 1 100%;
      }
    }
`;
```

And then, a few hundred lines below:

```
const PlanBody = styled.div`
/* Default value when container not hovered */
  flex: 1 1 0px;
`;
```

Btw, I can't declare `PlanBody` before `PlanContainer`. I could, but not in this case. I'm looking for another solution.

I tried using the `css` styled-components keyword like such, to no avail:

```
const PlanBodyStyles = css``;


const PlanContainer = styled.div<Props>`
  flex: 1 1 0px;

    &:hover {
      ${PlanBodyStyles} {
        flex: 1 1 100%;
      }
    }

`;
```

And then again, a few hundred lines below:

```
const PlanBody = styled.div`
/* Default value when container not hovered */
  flex: 1 1 0px;


  /* Override flex property */
  ${PlanBodyStyles}
`;
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer I would expect to give in 2021… but you can use `var` instead of `const`, to take advance of different [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) behavior